# Android ListView with Style to the elements issue; after scroll style changes automatically

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a Custom `ListView` in my application and it has some `TextView`s inside it to which the styles are provided at run time. When I scroll down the `ListView` and again scroll up, the styles given previously to the `TextView` changes to some different style.
Is there any way to prevent this?

I think, putting all the code here will make the page look ugly. So kindly follow these links for code-

[MyAdapter.java](http://www.4shared.com/file/-KKC9-_E/MyAdapter.html?)

[CustomListItem.java](http://www.4shared.com/file/AnnCl1Fc/CustomListItem.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix it. Just set the TextView with some default style in the "Convert View" like

```
textView.setTextAppearance(context , android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
```

in the ViewHolder constructor and in your method you use to set the elements to default state.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use custom `Adapter`? Maybe it is some issue with incorectly reusing convertView, can you post the code?

Or maybe it is just changing background color? In that case simple:

`android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`

in `ListView`'s XML will do the work.

Comment: Yes, I am applying CustomAdapter to my `ListView`. I am editing the question with the code links.